# C++ datatype conversion

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

Am reading a textfile and fetching the words from the file and putting them into an array of `const char*`. However my requirement is to convert those `const char*` variables into various data types like `DWORD,LPBYTE, WORD,ULONG` etc.

For the time being my implementation for conversion goes like this:

```
DWORD GetDword(const char* msg)
 {
   if (int strcmp(msg, "MyRequiredData") > 0)
        {
           return MyRequiredData ;
        }
 }
```

Assume "msg" is one string data from array. So that I would get the required data in the `DWORD` type in return via this method. And the same implementation for other types too.
Am concerned about almost hardcoding data here. Is there a better way to do it? Can I convert my strings into the data types I wish to?

Comment: I am not quite sure what exactly it is you're trying to achieve (your pseudocode example is a bit rich on "pseudo" and a bit lacking in "example". But it seems like you're looking to implement a parser; there are various ways to do this. Traditional is [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), modern and more powerful is [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html). Neither is a "quick" solution, as they require getting used to the technology, and will likely also require a complete rewrite of what you have.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DevSolar. What am trying to achieve here is, as you said parsing. Am currently looking into various ways including Boost.Spirit and Lexical_cast. Just trying to see if there are less difficult ways of implementing the parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial cases (converter) can be done with *numeric string conversion* section [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib), [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok), or simply [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

Advanced (parsing) - with [Lex/Yacc or Flex/Bison](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/), [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/), etc.

Advanced (unmarshalling/decoding) - with things like [Protobuf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers), [SBE](https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding), [Blink](http://blinkprotocol.org/), [XDR](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4506), [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One), etc.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the following form of type casting?

```
DWORD GetDword(const char* msg)
{
   return (DWORD) msg;
}
```

Though you have to make sure first if the content of `msg` can be converted to a DWORD to get the correct value.

Comment: Errr... you suggest casting a *string* (read from a *text* file) to *integer*?

Comment: He did say he was fetching "words", which I assume are convertible to other data types, to other functions. In his sample pseudocode/actual code mix, he wants to return the converted const char* value to DWORD. His question is about conversion, not parsing, isn't it?

Comment: He has a `msg` that is a C string (handling it with `strcmp()` in his pseudocode). That means even if it *does* contain numbers ("123"), that would be an array the ASCII values of the characters '1', '2' and '3' respecively... You want to convert those, you use `strtol()`, not a `(DWORD)` cast. But your answer does not even do *that* -- you are casting the **pointer** to DWORD...